# Как добавить иконку окна при сборке в pyinstaller?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, icon

Я сделал простое приложение на python с tkinter и хочу собрать его в pyinstaller. Я добавил иконку с помощью window.iconbitmap(). Что нужно, чтобы после сборки путь к иконке и сама иконка не терялись?

Оба ответа про иконку установщика, а меняет интересует иконка в левом верхнем углу открытой программы

Всё-таки нашёл готовый ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45628653/add-ico-file-to-executable-in-pyinstaller

Answer (score 1):

Ответ найден здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45628653/add-ico-file-to-executable-in-pyinstaller

Например:

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    application_path = sys._MEIPASS
elif __file__:
    application_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

iconFile = 'calculator.ico'

calculator.iconbitmap(default=os.path.join(application_path, iconFile))
```

И при сборке добавить `--add-data="noteicon.ico;."`

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете воспользоваться графическим интерфейсом для pyinstaller: auto-py-to-exe и там указать путь к иконке, которую нужно добавить при сборке. Вот ссылка на [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/)

А вот интерфейс:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно, здесь можно указать путь к иконке и она будет добавлена к проекту.